# How to fix face orientation when using screw modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, normals

I'm trying to model a camera lens using vertexes and screw modifier like spline modelling.
[image]
But face orientation is fully red and that becomes a problem when I try to use a boolean. Recalculating normals won't work because there are no normals to recalculate.
[image]
So are there any ways of solving this without applying screw modifier and then recalculating normals? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

**Click on the flip checkbox in the modifier settings**

[image: Flip]

**Set the angle to -360d**

[image: Negative Angle]